# My code is not returning the desire output

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to extract user detail from github api but when i try to achieve result convereting into json file but its giving me error:

```
URL = 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302'
r = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
print(r.json)
for aw in r.json():
    print(aw['id'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
 {'login': 'awais4302', 'id': 27438348, 'node_id': 'MDQ6VXNlcjI3NDM4MzQ4', `'avatar_url': 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/27438348?v=4', 'gravatar_id': '', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302', 'html_url': 'https://github.com/awais4302', 'followers_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302/followers', 'following_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302/following{/other_user}', 'gists_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302/gists{/gist_id}', 'starred_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302/starred{/owner}{/repo}', 'subscriptions_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302/subscriptions', 'organizations_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302/orgs', 'repos_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302/repos', 'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302/events{/privacy}', 'received_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302/received_events', 'type': 'User', 'site_admin': False, 'name': None, 'company': None, 'blog': '', 'location': None, 'email': None, 'hireable': None, 'bio': None, 'public_repos': 1, 'public_gists': 0, 'followers': 0, 'following': 0, 'created_at': '2017-04-13T16:53:35Z', 'updated_at': '2019-07-03T08:36:45Z', 'private_gists': 0, 'total_private_repos': 0, 'owned_private_repos': 0, 'disk_usage': 0, 'collaborators': 0, 'two_factor_authentication': False, 'plan': {'name': 'free', 'space': 976562499, 'collaborators': 0, 'private_repos': 10000}}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6d0e261b00e5> in <module>
     25 print(r.json())
     26 for aw in r.json():
---> 27     print(aw['login'])
     28 
     29 

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I want output like extract name, location etc all attribute of the user from given link.

Comment: ...what is the error you are getting? what is `headers`? please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Please also print out `r.json()`

Comment: From your error code, it appears that `aw` is a string, not a dictionary. This is why `aw['id']` raises an error.

Comment: Thanks @ItamarMushkin I'm new to python  what should i do then ?

Comment: You need to show us the actual JSON. Probably, the data is a dictionary, so iterating through gives you just the keys.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman you can see Actual JSON output in output section. You're right data is dictionary. Its giving me only keys could you tell me how to get values of these keys

Comment: There is no need for the loop. Just do `data = r.json()` then `data['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below.

```
URL = 'https://api.github.com/users/awais4302'
r = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)

for k, v in r.json().items():
  print k, ":", v
```

To access value of a specific key, e.g. `id`

```
data = r.json()
print data['id']
```

Explanation:
`json` method returns a dictionary, and you were trying to loop over key only.